# A Hölder version of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma on essentially bounded functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Does there exist a Hölder (not necessarily linear) projection from $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to any finite-dimensional linear subspace?  This is known when $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is replaced by a finite-dimensional Euclidean space (and it is the subject of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma) but when does this result break?

Comment: Maybe composing the map on the link below with a linear projection and applying JL lemma?: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/Holder-FOCS2018.pdf

Comment: I took a look but isn't this map defined only between finite-dimensional normed spaces?

Comment: The question as asked has an easy and uninteresting answer : any finite dimensional subspace of any normed space is the image of a bounded linear projection (just by Hahn-Banach). The content of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma is quite different : it says that a finite *set* of points can be embedded with low distorsion is a space of dimension much smaller (logarithmic in the size), and moreover the embedding is the restriction of a linear map defined everywhere.

Comment: I do not know if this answers what you meant to ask, but there is no such analogous statement to the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma for $L^\infty$. Namely there are sets $X$ of cardinality $n$ in $L^\infty$ such that, if there is a map from $X$ to a normed space which is Hoelder-continuous as well as its inverse, then the dimension of the normed space is a positive power of  $n$.

Comment: This result also touches upon the Johnson-Lindenstraus lemma for $L^{\infty}$ (and has many related references) https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1496866

Comment: @Mikael What is the reference to this article?  Is there a bound on the Hoelder exponent (there must be since the paper posted by AIM_BLB gives a strict upper bound of 1).

Comment: @AnnieTheKatsu I do not know it this is written anywhere, but this follows from the proof in the paper "On the distortion required for embedding finite metric spaces into normed spaces" by Matousek, see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1380650

Comment: Matousek's paper formally is only interested in Lipschitz embeddings, but the proof actually works with any coarse embedding (in particular Hoelder embeddings).